# Initializing structures with dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c89

I am having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically allocate memory and then initialize a struct with that memory. I am trying to make a binary tree and then set the children to have NULL as their 'word', this was I can test for NULL and insert more nodes as necessary. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
   char* word;
   int count;
   struct node* leftchild;
   struct node* rightchild;
};

int main(void){
   struct node *rootnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   scanf("%s ",rootnode.word);
   rootnode.count=countchars(rootnode.word);/*haven't written this func yet*/

   rootnode.leftchild=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node* leftchild = rootnode.leftchild;
   rootnode.leftchild.word=NULL;

   rootnode.rightchild=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node* rightchild = rootnode.rightchild;
   rootnode.rightchild.word=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Just for starters, you need to allocate the buffer used for "word" when you need it.

Comment: Next, the usual practice is just to set the child pointers to NULL to indicate non-existance.

Comment: The correct spelling of `countchars` is actually `strlen` (and you need to include the `<string.h>` header too).

Comment: The format string `"%s "` with the trailing space is dangerous to use with interactive input. It won't return until you type: (1) an optional string of white space, (2) a string of one or more non-white space characters, (3) a string of one or more white-space characters, followed by (4) a non-white space character. It is (4) that is surprising, but until it comes across a non-white space character, it doesn't know whether it has finished processing (3).  This behaviour is typically not what you want. It's OK if the input comes strictly from a file, but not for terminal input most of the time.

Comment: You need to allocate space for `rootnode.word` before you read the input, or read the input into a buffer and then allocate space for a copy of the buffer.  You should also be checking the results of `malloc()` to ensure you don't dereference null pointers.  And, as DrC pointed out, you should simply set `rootnode.leftchild = NULL;` and `rootnode.rightchild = NULL;` rather than allocate full structures with a null `word` pointer.  All else apart, it simplifies adding the second and subsequent words to the list considerably.

Comment: I'd just make word a char[100] or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct node *` is a pointer type. To access its values, you need to dereference them. The following shows what you may have been going for:

```
typedef struct node_t{
    char* word;
    int count;
    struct node_t* leftchild;
    struct node_t* rightchild;
} node;

int main(void){
    node *rootnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    //scanf("%s ", rootnode.word);
    //rootnode.count = countchars(rootnode.word);/*haven't written this func yet*/
    rootnode->leftchild = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    node* leftchild = rootnode->leftchild;
    leftchild->word = NULL;
    rootnode->rightchild = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    node* rightchild = rootnode->rightchild;
    rightchild->word = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `scanf` line is commented - you need to allocate space for the word buffer before you can read into it. I leave that as an exercise to you :)

Comment: Thanks this really cleared things up for me. One of the main things that I had trouble with was that rootnode.leftchild is not the same as rootnode->leftchild. I just wrote it as (*rootnode).leftchild

Comment: Using `(*somePointer).` is the same as using `somePointer->`. The latter is syntactic sugar that makes reading the code easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your following logic is not correct:

```
struct node *rootnode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
scanf("%s ",rootnode.word);
rootnode.count=countchars(rootnode.word);/*haven't written this func yet*/
```

In the above code, you have allocated the memory for the *struct node*. Now *word* is of pointer of type *char*. So far you have allocated the memory which can store the address into this variable.

Now you need to allocate the memory to copy into this particular variable. You need to find or define the maximum length of string here. For an example(100)

```
rootnode.word = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
// Now you can use this memory further in your program.
```

BTW you need to write the logic to *free* the memory as well.

Comment: Minor comment - sizeof(char) is definitively equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just for starters, you need to allocate the buffer used for "word" when you need it.  Next, the usual practice is just to set the child pointers to NULL to indicate non-existance.

So

```
node.count=strlen(string); /* hope this is what you want, if not use strlen(string on next line) */
node.word = malloc(node.count+1);
strcpy(node.word, string);
node.leftChild = node.rightChild = NULL;
```